# add php variable into wordpress mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert into `DB` data from an ajax query. When I test the function with simple text it works :

```
array('reference_id'=> 'test'),
array('checkin_time'=> 'test'),
```

but my PHP variables do not while they are correct (tested by alert(), they are both strings)

```
array('reference_id'=> $calendartime),
array('checkin_time'=> $reference_id),
```

Here is the full code in my template functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'       ) ) );

function addCheckin(){
   global $wpdb, $calendartime, $reference_id;
   $calendartime = $_POST['calendar_time'];
   $reference_id = $_POST['reference_id'];

   if($wpdb->insert('checkin',
   array('reference_id'=> $calendartime),
   array('checkin_time'=> $reference_id),
   array( '%s'), 
   array( '%s') )===FALSE){

       echo "Error";
   }else {}
   die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_addCheckin', 'addCheckin');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCheckin', 'addCheckin');
```

And the `jquery` :

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data:{
              action: addCheckin,
              reference_id: $('.reference input').val(),
              calendar_time: calendar
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
   });
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress Insert seems to be wrong. It should be:

```
$wpdb->insert('checkin',
array('reference_id' => $calendartime,
'checkin_time' => $reference_id),
array( '%s', '%s') )
```

I also think your AJAX post JavaScript should be like:

```
$.post(   MyAjax.ajaxurl,  {
            data:{
              action: addCheckin,
              reference_id: $('.reference input').val(),
              calendar_time: calendar
            },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
   });
```

Comment: I removed the if, else etc. I did not event realised there were here... but it still does not work :/

Comment: `$wpdb->insert` returns an id on success. Did you check your `checkin` table?

Comment: My checkin table (which is composed of id, reference_id, and checkin_time  for the info) remains the same. Nothing is inserted.

Comment: I think there is some syntax error with your JavaScript. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I replaced my JavaScript code with yours, and tried with data text instead of    reference_id: $('.reference input').val(),
calendar_time: calendar
 
but still not working. I think functions.php do not get the POST variable properly as it does not insert them, no matter what's in it.

Comment: 'not working' doesn't help solve the issue. You should provide some kind of error or something to analyse.

Comment: I think the problem is here : wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'       ) ) );

My file name is form.s not my-ajax-request'. I test and tell you

Comment: I believe you enqueued form.js aswell. Why not test providing the same handle to wp_localize_script?

Answer (score 0):

Update : I added the following code to my theme header.php (It was for a page using Contact Form 7) :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.40.0-2013.08.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.5.2'></script>
```

and now it works with the following code :

```
var data = {
          'action': 'form',
          'reference_id': $('.reference input').val(),
          'calendar_time': calendar
     };

$.post( form.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I updated the name of function, callback etc. They all have the same, Now I get as an alert : undefined, even if variables are text. Any ideas ?